# How to take records basing on date

Tags: mysql, sql

In my datatable, I have a column named `special_id` that contains values which are not unique.

For example:

```
+-----+-----+------------+-------------------------+
| ... | ... | special_id |        add_date         |
+-----+-----+------------+-------------------------+
| ... | ... |       1111 | 2018-02-02 09:42:11.993 |
| ... | ... |       2222 | 2018-02-01 09:42:11.993 |
| ... | ... |       1111 | 2018-01-31 09:42:11.993 |
| ... | ... |       3333 | 2018-01-02 09:42:11.993 |
| ... | ... |       4444 | 2018-01-22 09:42:11.993 |
+-----+-----+------------+-------------------------+
```

I would like to know whether I can (using SQL) `SELECT` the **newest** record, with matching `special_id`, based on `add_date` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.add_date = (select max(t2.add_date) from t t2 where t2.special_id = t.special_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If only getting the first record is what you're interested in, LIMIT will do the trick for you. So you could try

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY add_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do the trick.

```
SELECT special_id, MAX(add_date)
FROM test_tbl
GROUP BY special_id;
```